# Nodejs/Edgejs with Breezejs?

Tags: node.js, breeze, edgejs

We are interested in using [breezejs](http://www.breezejs.com/) with nodejs by way of [edgejs](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/). To do so, we need to bypass ASP.NET WebAPI. Any insight on how to do this? It looks like we need to

1. Get metadata out using `EFContextProvider.Metadata()` and convert to JSON (using `JsonFormatter`?)
2. Get `IQueryable<EntityType>` in an appropriate way for queries. What's the right shape for this? How does the query actually get executed?
3. Save changes using `EFContextProvider.SaveChanges` with a JSON object retrieved from the client. (using `JsonFormatter`?)

Are there any ideas on how to do this? Is there anything we are missing?

Answer (score 1):

We will be releasing a Node/Express/Mongo Db sample and adapters within the next couple of weeks.  Some of the code from this work should be illustrative in trying to accomplish what you want.

Prior to that, your best bet is to look at the Breeze.WebApi source.  Most of this code is NOT  WebApi specific and you may be able to refactor it.  This is something that we will be looking at doing ourselves at some point in the future when we implement a ServiceStack alternative to  WebApi.